# How to use Jsforce library in Angular2 and Ionic2 App?

Tags: jsforce

I want to study Ionic2 app and try to use jsforce to access Salesforce API in my app, but I don't know how to import jsforce to my ionic2 app?

https://jsforce.github.io/

Comment: const jsforce: any = require('jsforce');